# ModelState Validation in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, modelstate, actionfilterattribute

the class has a property `UserId` which type of `ApplicationUser` and its required, and of course we can not pass it from view to controller because of security reasons.

Now when the controller checks the state of model the model is not in a correct state because there is no UserId Value and it returns the view back, if I use the view model the class has more than 50 properties and assigning the values from view model to class and then save it it is very tedious and difficult to do it for saving editing and so on, any advice to come out from this problem

thanks

Comment: Are you using `ASPNET MVC`?

Comment: @Phong yes i am using MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyhow thanks for the cooperation for solving this problem
the easiest way that i found to return a **UserId** from a class, just one line of code is required inside class constructor

```
public constructor()
{
  UserId =  ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.GetUserId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Action Filters attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) to **Auto Bind Property**.

Let's say we have **`UserSettingMetaModel`** with **`UserId`** property.

```
public interface IAutoBindingUserId
{
    int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class UserSettingMetaModel : IAutoBindingUserId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    // The rest of properties
}
```

In **UserSetting** controller, we have

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AutoBindProperty]
    public JsonResult Add(UserSettingMetaModel metaModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Behind the sense of **`AutoBindProperty`** Attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class AutoBindPropertyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var actionParams = filterContext.ActionParameters.Values.FirstOrDefault();

        Bind<IAutoBindingUserId>(model => model.UserId = 123, actionParams);
        // Assuming that you know the way get userId value here.
    }

    private static void Bind<T>(Action<T> doBinding, object actionParams) where T : class
    {
        if (actionParams is T model)
        {
            doBinding(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mohammad Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help? Don't forget to give me an upvote my answer was useful to you ^^!